# Plotting: DensityPlot produces artifacts

Tags: plotting, programming

I am trying to plot the electric potentials of bouncing balls using the following code:

```
g = 0.1;
Tmax = 100;
n = 6;
pos = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
charge = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10];

sol = NDSolve[
    Flatten@Table[{
        With[{i = i}, 
            {(x[i])''[t] == 0,
             (x[i])'[0] == 0,
             (y[i]'')[t] == -g,
             (y[i])'[0] == 0,
             x[i][0] == pos[[i, 1]],
             y[i][0] == pos[[i, 2]],
             WhenEvent[
                 y[i][t] < -1, {y[i]'[t] -> -0.95 y[i]'[t], 
                 y[i][t] -> y[i][t] + 0.05}]
             }
         ]
 }, {i, 1, n}], Flatten@Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, Tmax}, PrecisionGoal -> 2];

Manipulate[Graphics[
    Table[
        With[{p = Evaluate[
            {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. First[sol]]},
        Disk[p, 0.05]], {i, 1, n}], PlotRange -> 1.05], {t, 0, Tmax}]

PotentialAnimated[x_, y_, t_] := 
    Sum[charge[[i]]/
        If[Norm[({x, y} - {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. sol)] > 0.001, 
           Norm[({x, y} - {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. sol)], 0.001],
    {i, 1, n}]

Manipulate[
    DensityPlot[PotentialAnimated[x, y, t], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

This^ last command should plot the potentials in my box caused by the charged balls jumping up and down, but I get an almost fractal looking artifact from my lower left to my upper right corner. Any ideas why this is happening ?

// part 2

not directly related but I feel like it would be a waste to start a new question just for this.

Im now trying to combine the two plots like this:

Manipulate[
 Show[{DensityPlot[
    PotentialAnimated[x, y, t], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], Graphics[
    Table[
     With[{p = {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. First[sol]},
      {ColorData["TemperatureMap", (charge[[i]] + 10)/20], 
       Disk[p, 0.5]}
      ]
     , {i, 1, n}]
    , PlotRange -> 10.5, Background -> Black]}], {t, 0, Tmax}]

for charges ranging from -10 to 10 , but it seems like the colors get "clipped" on the density plot[image: clipped]

how can I fix it so colours near the balls dont just go white.

thx for the help so far

catadoxas

Comment: Please, format your code accordingly :)

Answer (score 8):

This happens because `sol` contains the symbols `x` and `y`.  These are global symbols.  The function `PotentialAnimated` uses them without localization.  There's be a conflict when `DensityPlot` assigns temporary values to `x` and `y`.

The fix is to localize them:

```
PotentialAnimated[u_, v_, t_] := 
 Block[{x, y}, 
  Sum[charge[[i]]/EuclideanDistance[{u, v}, {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. sol[[1]]], {i, 1, n}]
 ]
```

This function works as expected.

But what exactly happened when `x` and `y` were not properly localized to `PotentialAnimated`?

Here's an result I got while experimenting with `Table`:

```
In[39]:= Table[{x, y, PotentialAnimated[x, y, 20]}, {x, {.7}}, {y, {.7}}]
Out[39]= {{{0.7, 0.7, 1035.03}}}

In[40]:= PotentialAnimated[0.7, 0.7, 20]
Out[40]= 27.7281
```

`Table`, and `DensityPlot` too, localizes `x` and `y` using `Block`.  In other words, these functions assign temporary values to `x` and `y`.  Due to an accident `PotentialAnimated` still works in this case, as it relies on `ReplaceAll`.  It doesn't really matter if you make a replacement as `x[i][t] /. {x -> ...}` or `42[i][t] /. {42 -> ...}`, up to the point where that magic number `42` gets repeated.  This happened in your case when `x` became equal to `y`, which changed the replacement.

Hope this hastily typed up explanation is clear enough ...

**Morale: don't leave dangling global symbols when defining functions.**  Or if you like: when using dynamic languages that support dynamic scoping, things can go wrong in weird and unexpected ways.

In your case you can try using `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve`, which eliminates the need for these symbols.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve the problem by using an auxiliary function ... See Szabolcs' answer for the explanation.

```
PotentialAnimated[u_, v_, t_] :=  Sum[charge[[i]]/ 
               EuclideanDistance[{u, v}, {x[i][t], y[i][t]} /. sol[[1]]], {i, 1,  n}]

q[f_, x_, y_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := DensityPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, opts]

GraphicsRow[{
  q[PotentialAnimated[x, y, 10], x, y, PlotPoints -> 20,  MaxRecursion -> 5],
  DensityPlot[PotentialAnimated[x, y, 10], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
              PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 5]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can add `Evaluated -> True` or plain `Evaluate` the argument to fix the problem.  (Yes: But why?)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zh00nhizfq6rem/Screenshot%202014-06-19%2019.45.03.png) ...  which brings us to the solution: `x` and `y` should be localized in `PotentialAnimated`!!

Comment: @Szabolcs You may also try `PotentialAnimated[u_?NumericQ, v_, t_] := ...` and it always shows the imperfections

Comment: I typed it up in an answer.

Comment: thanks for the amazing and quick responses